# SQL запрос в php

Tags: mysqli, php, update, select, sql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите что не так в моих запросах ибо они не выполняются:

```
$lastVisit = "SELECT data FROM users WHERE socid = '$idsql'";
$rezLastVisit = mysqli_query($sql, $lastVisit);
echo "Последнее посещение: ",$rezLastVisit;
$up_data = "UPDATE users SET data = '$tek_data' WHERE socid = '$idsql'";
$up_data_add = mysqli_query($sql, $up_data);
```

Таблица users, в ней 3 поля: name , socid , data. Все значения которые передаю в таблицу string.

Comment: Ошибки какие выбивает? Синтаксис изменить:

    $lastVisit = "SELECT data FROM users WHERE socid = '".$idsql."'";

Проверить правильно ли указали название полей, таблиц etc. Правильно ли подключились и вообще, есть ли подключение к БД?

Comment: запрос INSERT выполнился правильно, все было занесено в таблицу. `$new_user = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$namesql','$idsql','$tek_data')";
$new_user_add = mysqli_query($sql, $new_user);`
переменная $rezLastVisit является object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { } Как её вывести? Никаких ошибок не выдаёт.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch_array()` не забыли?

```
$resource = mysqli_query($sql, $lastVisit);
$rezLastVisit = fetch_array($resource);
echo "Последнее посещение: ".$rezLastVisit['data'];
```

P.S. переходите уже на ООП

Comment: > P.S. переходите уже на ООП

@Gedweb, просветите на счёт ООП в данном контексте.